# sed function to replace any config file entry

Tags: sed, scripting, configuration

I'm trying to write a build script for SLES/RHEL that modifies config files to conform to our company standards.  Some configs are formatted as setting = value and some are just setting value.  I'm using sed currently and feel I'm almost there but it's not working when there is no equals sign.

Current code: (Sorry I'm not very good at formatting these properly yet...)

```
$ cat test.conf
setting1 value1 
setting2= value2
setting3 = value3
setting4 =value4
```

Current (test) function:

```
#!/bin/bash
replace () {  
file=$1  
var=$2  
new_value=$3



sed -e "s/^$var=.*/$var = $new_value/" -e "s/^$var =.*/$var = $new_value/" -e "s/^$var.*/$var = $new_value/" -e "s/^$var /$var $new_value/" "$file"|grep $var  

}


replace test.conf setting1 value1new 
replace test.conf setting2 value2new  
replace test.conf setting3 value3new  
replace test.conf setting4 value4new
```

However I get this as a result:

```
$ ./functiontest
setting1 value1new= value1new 
setting2 value2new= value2new 
setting3 value3new= value3new 
setting4 value4new= value4new
```

It works if I take out the last sed portion, but only where there is an equals sign.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The goal that I am going for is for the final product to look like this:
`setting1 value1new`  
`setting2 = value2new`  
`setting3 = value3new`  
`setting4 = value4new`

Comment: Really the whole idea of regular expressions is to **avoid** matching every variant pattern case-by-case: for example, you could match zero or more spaces followed by an *optional* equals sign `"s/^${var} *=\{0,1\}.*/${var} = ${new_value}/"`

Comment: What was the last portion meant to do anyway?

Comment: @Philippos is that portion question directed at me or @steeldriver?

Comment: @steeldriver I fully agree.  I'm no expert at scripting though I never intended to create a case-by-case match, I just didn't know how to do a "catch all" statement.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the set of "similar" ***sed*** substitutions to the following:

```
cat replace.sh 
#!/bin/bash
replace () {
var=$2  
new_val=$3

sed -e "s/^$var *= *.*/$var = $new_val/; s/^$var [^=]*$/$var $new_val/" "$1" | grep $var 

}

replace test.conf setting1 value1new 
replace test.conf setting2 value2new  
replace test.conf setting3 value3new  
replace test.conf setting4 value4new
```

---

***Usage***:

```
bash replace.sh
```

The output:

```
setting1 value1new
setting2 = value2new
setting3 = value3new
setting4 = value4new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "s/^$var[ =].*/$var = $new_value/p" "$file"
```

It's sufficient to follow the variable by either space or equal sign, then one replacement fits all.

By using option `-n` and the `p` after the replacement you don't need the `grep`. The `sed` did already grep the right line.

Comment: Sorry I should have pulled the grep, it was just for my troubleshooting, as was the lack of inclusion of sed -i.